# Filtering FirebaseListObservable

Tags: angular, firebase, observable, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm trying to filter my FirebaseListObservable:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
...
jobListRef$: FirebaseListObservable<Job[]>;
...
this.jobListRef$ = this.database.list('job-list',
          { query:
              {
                orderByChild: "state",
                equalTo: "passive"
              }
          }).filter(item => item.employer === this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid));
```

But I get just:

> Type 'Observable< any>' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable< Job[]>'. Property '$ref' is missing in type 'Observable< any>'.

I saw that this issue should be already fixed in **angularfire2@^2.0.0-beta.7.1-pre**, but I use **angularfire2@^4.0.0-rc.2**

Comment: You need to upgrade to latest: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/releases/tag/5.0.0-rc.3

Comment: @Sampath I've tried right now, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to upgrade to [**latest**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/releases/tag/5.0.0-rc.3). After that:

```
jobListRef$: Observable<Job[]>;
this.jobListRef$ = this.database.list('job-list', query =>
        {
            return query.orderByChild("state").equalTo("active");
        }
).valueChanges();
```